# Secure long-term parking in Johannesburg

Tags: automobiles, security, south-africa

I will be taking a one-month trip departing from the airport in Johannesburg, South Africa and need a secure place to park my car. I see that the airport has [long-term parking](http://www.acsa.co.za/home.asp?pid=3651), but is it safe to leave my car there for one month? Are there are any other options for long-term secure parking in Johannesburg?

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that [one reference on the Lonely Planet forums](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=1964195) reckons the South Gate parking is under shade netting - which in Joburg's hailstorms may not offer the protection you desire.

However, [your link](http://www.acsa.co.za/home.asp?pid=3651) would seem to indicate that's only sections P5 and P6.

Another option would be to rent a storage garage big enough to fit your car.  They have 24 hour security, and there are some near the airport.

Finally, you could consider [Omni Park](http://www.omnipark.co.za) - who manage several car park locations in the Cape (I realise that's a different area), and may have contacts or branches in or around Joburg.